# Wordpress returning 404 for multisite pages

Tags: php, multisite, permalinks, apache

I'm trying to configure a WP Multisite to run locally, all is fine on the server, but getting this to run locally is turning into quite a pain. The issue I'm currently seeing is that some of the sites won't load anything except the home page when the permalink settings are anything but plain. The inconsistency is confusing me.

So far I've added the following code:

wp-config.php

```
define('WP_DEBUG', true);

/* Multisite */
define('WP_ALLOW_MULTISITE', true);

/* Multisite stage two */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', '******');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/wp/******/site/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /wp/******/site/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?wp-admin$ $1wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $2 [L]
RewriteRule ^([_0-9a-zA-Z-]+/)?(.*\.php)$ $2 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

I've...

- Updated all the site values in the DB
- Reset the permalinks multiple times
- Deactivated all plugins
- Made sure the rewrite module is turned on

All the searches for this issue bring me to the same 3 solutions I've tried again and again. Any help will be hugely appreciated!

Comment: What do you have in your `wp_blogs` table and also each of the `wp_#_options` tables for `siteurl` and `home`?

Comment: In `wp_#_options` I have `http://10.0.19.14/wp/****/site/{theme}` for `siteurl` & `home`. In `wp_blogs` I have `10.0.19.14` for `domain` & `/wp/****/site/{theme}` for `path`

On one of the sites live (which is under development) I've just test changed a permalink setting, thinking this would be a closed environment to that theme, I now have this same error live! The urgency has just got a lot larger :/ I appreciate you trying to help

Comment: I'm not sure if you should have the theme in the wp_#_options URLs as these normally just point to the root URL - try just `http://10.0.19.14/wp/****/site/` if that is the root of your WordPress installation.

Comment: Unfortunately removing the theme name from the `wp_#_options` tables makes all pages of the changed sites display index.php only

Comment: Silly question, but do you have `mod_rewrite` enabled on your local server?

Comment: I do, I have multiple WordPress installs working locally with no issue. This is the only one that's causing a headache. I have rechecked this to make sure, and it is indeed enabled.

Comment: I do vaguely remember having a few issues with a past multi-site install. You can try setting `define('ADMIN_COOKIE_PATH', '/');
define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', '');
define('COOKIEPATH', '');
define('SITECOOKIEPATH', '');` and see if those help at all

Comment: It doesn't make a difference I'm afraid. I really do appreciate you spending time on this, I feel I'm at the end of options to take :(

Comment: I don't think you can use the chat feature yet, but may be easier to work thorough on there. Do you have `wp_debug` set to true?

Comment: I do, it's not showing any errors. I just go straight to the 404 page. The only time I can get to a page is when I place the permalinks back to plain

Comment: Hello @AlexanderHolsgrove, thank you for the help and patience today. It seems to be solved, it also seems that this was ticking timebomb. The issue was with the creation of a custom post type, this custom post type included a rewrite rule and therefore should have be tightly scoped to the site that needed it. From this I imagine that whenever the permalinks got flushed the site was destined to break. So glad this has been solved, again thank you for suggestions.

Comment: I think you did the hard work here, but glad you got it working. A good plugin to help with all things rewrite related is [Rewrite Riles Inspector](https://wordpress.org/plugins/rewrite-rules-inspector/). Welcome to the site by the way!